# Prevent Swift from Chaining Imports

Tags: ios, swift, import

I'm following the [VIPER](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/) architecture for my app, and currently working on the repository layer (MyRepository). My `NSManagedObject` subclasses have the line `import CoreData`, which is of course necessary to see `NSManagedObject`. These subclasses are all explicitly marked `internal`.

My question is, how do I prevent `import MyRepository` from also implicitly importing CoreData? When I Cmd+Click `import MyRepository` I see a file like this (importing CoreData).

```
import CoreData
import Foundation
import MyRepository
import MyRepository.Swift
```

Ideally, presenter / view projects would know nothing about CoreData's existence at all, they would only receive the POSOs (Plain Old Swift Objects?) that are mapped from the CD Entities.

No `public` classes/functions have any reference to anything used in `CoreData`, only `internal` classes/functions do. So I don't see the additional import as necessary.